# when i am running the following code ...I am getting an error

Tags: mysql, jsp, jakarta-ee

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Login </TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY bgcolor="#ffffcc">
  <font size="+3" color="red"><br>Welcome !!!!</font>
  <FORM action="" method="get">
    <TABLE style="background-color: #ECE5B6;" WIDTH="30%" >

      <TR>
          <TH width="50%">id</TH>
          <TD width="50%"><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="id1"></TD>
      </tr>
<TR>
    <TH width="50%">password</TH>
 <TD width="50%"><INPUT TYPE="password" NAME="pass1"></TD>
  </tr>

  <TR>
      <TH></TH>
      <TD width="50%"><INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="submit"></TD>
  </tr>
   </TABLE>

<%
   String id = request.getParameter("id1");
   String  pass= request.getParameter("pass1");

   String connectionURL ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
   Connection connection = null;


   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
   int updateQuery = 0;
   if(id!=null && pass!=null){
   if(id!="" && pass!="" ){
   try {
       connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL,"root","dhawanbhai1");

   Statement st=connection.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select id,password from userpass");  
      while(rs.next())  
           {  
           String username=rs.getString(1);  
           String password=rs.getString(2);  
           if(id.equals(username) && pass.equals(password)){  
               session.setAttribute("username",id);  
               response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8081/LoginExample/Welcome.jsp");  
           }  
                   else{  
               response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8081/LoginExample/LoginError.jsp");  
                   }  
       }  
  }            
                   catch (Exception ex) {
       out.println("Unable to connect to database.");
       }
       finally {
           pstatement.close();
           connection.close();
            }


%>
  </FORM>
 </body> 
</html>
```

Error :
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:

---

type Exception report
message Unable to compile class for JSP: 
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: [40] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\jabaraku\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\LoginExample\org\apache\jsp\LoginPage_jsp.java]
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

An error occurred at line: [149] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\jabaraku\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\LoginExample\org\apache\jsp\LoginPage_jsp.java]
Syntax error, insert "else Statement" to complete IfStatement

An error occurred at line: [149] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\jabaraku\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\LoginExample\org\apache\jsp\LoginPage_jsp.java]
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block

An error occurred at line: [149] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\jabaraku\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\LoginExample\org\apache\jsp\LoginPage_jsp.java]
Syntax error, insert "else Statement" to complete IfStatement

An error occurred at line: [149] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\jabaraku\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\LoginExample\org\apache\jsp\LoginPage_jsp.java]
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block

An error occurred at line: [161] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\jabaraku\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\LoginExample\org\apache\jsp\LoginPage_jsp.java]
Syntax error on token "}", delete this token

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.

---

Apache Tomcat/7.0.47

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your error output. You dont close the `if` statements in your code. You should have two `}` after the `finally` statement.

Answer (score 0):

After finally you should have **}** please check.